# Using `.of` Constructor on Sanctuary Maybe

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, fantasyland, sanctuary

I'm working through a [tutorial](https://james-forbes.com/?/posts/the-perfect-api) on functional programming that shows the following code example using the sanctuary.js library:

```
var S = require('sanctuary')
var Maybe = S.Maybe

S.add(
  Maybe.of(3)
  ,Maybe.of(5)
)
.map(n => n * n)
```

I get the error `Maybe.of is not a function`. The sanctuary.js [API documentation](https://sanctuary.js.org/#of) shows an example of using `.of` as `S.of(S.Maybe, 42)`, so I modified my code like this:

```
...
S.of(S.Maybe, 3)
,S.of(S.Maybe, 5)
```

And I get the error:

```
add :: FiniteNumber -> FiniteNumber -> FiniteNumber
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
            1

The value at position 1 is not a member of ‘FiniteNumber’.
```

I don't see any documentation on the sanctuary site about the FiniteNumber type class. How do I make this code work? And is there any way to chain the sanctuary `.of` constructor onto type classes, so the example on the tutorial site works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add two Maybes, you can only add two numbers. Notice that the tutorial you read uses `add = R.lift(R.add)`.

In sanctuary, you can use

```
S.lift2(S.add, S.Just(3), S.Just(5)) // Just(8)
```

or

```
S.ap(S.map(S.add, S.Just(3)), S.Just(5)) // Just(8)
S.Just(3).map(S.add).ap(S.Just(5)) // Just(8)
```

or

```
S.ap(S.ap(S.Just(S.add), S.Just(3)), S.Just(5)) // Just(8)
S.Just(S.add).ap(S.Just(3)).ap(S.Just(5)) // Just(8)
```

Comment: thanks for the help on this and other FP questions I've posted. Can you tell me why I get a "`TypeError: Maybe.of is not a function`" with your first example? I've added `let Maybe = S.Maybe` to prevent a reference error when using `Maybe`, but how do I get it to allow me to chain the sanctuary `of` constructor onto `Maybe` as in your example?

Comment: Oops, I have never actually used Sanctuary. Looks like you indeed need to use `S.of(Maybe, …)` or `S.Just(…)` instead. Or `S.Maybe['fantasy-land/of'](…)`, although I wouldn't recommend that.

Answer (score 1):

For wrapping some value to `Maybe` you should use function `S.toMaybe` instead `Maybe.of`